# Build works, but precompile during publish fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, precompile

There are no issues when:

- Building the project
- Running in debug mode via IIS Express
- Running in debug mode via IIS
- Publishing to a server with "precompile" off

Publish settings:
[image: Example settings]

Additional information:

- "Do not merge" options work
- Fails during "csc.exe"

Error:

The type or namespace name 'Owin' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

File:

Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs

Relevant code from `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
....
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyNameSpace.MyProject.Startup))]
```

Development Environment:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the proper references are not present during the publish process (I'd love to know why, but I'm unable to figure it out).

To fix this, simply move the Owin code into a new file `AssemblyInfo.Owin.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyNameSpace.MyProject.Startup))]
```